# Can a capacitor be charged without having resistance in the circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, batteries

I was looking for the fact when a capacitor is directly connected to battery without resistor what will happen? 
If possible then tell the time for charging.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of ideal circuit theory, if an ideal constant voltage source with voltage across $v_S = V_{DC}$ is, at time $t = 0$, instantaneously connected to an ideal, uncharged capacitor, the voltage across the capacitor is a step

$$v_C(t) = V_{DC}u(t)$$

and so the current through is an impulse

$$i_C(t) = CV_{DC}\delta(t)$$

This is *clearly* unphysical so there's something missing from the model. As others have pointed out, a *physical* voltage source cannot supply arbitrarily large current and so the voltage across the capacitor cannot instantaneously change (since the current through is finite, the voltage rate of change is finite).

In addition, the area enclosed by the source, conductors, and capacitor is not zero and so there is a self-inductance of the circuit and resistance of the conductors that can limit the instantaneous current and its rate of change.

Further, physical capacitors actually have an associated inductance and series resistance.

So, to properly model this using ideal circuit elements, all of these 'parasitic' inductances and resistances must be added to the ideal circuit model to more accurately predict the physical charging current.

---

From the comments:

> The voltage at a capacitor can not "jump", this is also well known
>   from circuit theory

In *ideal* circuit theory, the voltage across a capacitor *can* be discontinuous if the current through is an impulse.  As an example, and because of this push back from the comments, I'll post this screenshot from the book "Electric Circuits and Networks" (via Google books):

[image]

Comment: " ...if an ideal constant voltage source with voltage across vS=VDCvS=VDC is, at time t=0, instantaneously connected to an ideal, uncharged capacitor, the voltage across the capacitor is a step

vC(t)=VDCu(t). " Why would the voltage be a step function at t=0, given the fact that the unloaded capacitor is an ideal shortcut at t=0?  How do derive the step function vC(t)=VDCu(t)? At t=0, we have 2 concurrent ideal voltage sources directly connected, with different voltages (one is <> zero, the other is zero). How do you exactly yield the step voltage at t=0 like you stated?

Comment: This result is well known in ideal circuit theory.  The time rate of change of voltage across an ideal capacitor is proportional to the current through.  An ideal voltage source can supply arbitrarily large current and thus, can change the voltage across an ideal capacitor in arbitrarily short time.  If you find this difficult to accept, insert a series resistance and find that the voltage across the capacitor is $$v_C(t) = V_{DC}\left(1 - e^{-t/RC}\right)u(t)$$ and then take the limit as $R \rightarrow 0$ to find that the capacitor voltage goes to a step.

Comment: 1. An ideal unloaded capacitor can take arbitrarily large currents since it is an ideal shortcut at time t_0.

Comment: 1. An ideal unloaded capacitor can take arbitrarily large currents since it is an ideal shortcut at time t_0.  2. Also t (i.e. the timespan since connecting) must be taken as limit -> 0, so it is still difficult to accept. 3. The voltage at a capacitor can not "jump", this is also well known from circuit theory since it is the integral over the current, which is not defined here,which can't be calculated in this circuit.

Comment: @xeeka, either you see this or you don't:   $$\frac{1}{C}\int_{-\infty}^{t}\delta(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau = \frac{1}{C}u(t)$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68908/discussion-between-xeeka-and-alfred-centauri).

Comment: @xeekza, see update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Every battery has an internal resistance. This the time of charging would be defined by the value of this resistance plus the resistance of the connecting cables, and finally by the internal resistance of the capacitor. In an ideal case of a superconducting battery and capacitor, the charging time would be defined by the inductive resistance of the connecting cables.

Answer (score 0):

In the real world, each of the simple passive components (resistor, inductor, capacitor) contain a little of each other. That is, a resistor has an inductance, a capacitor has a resistance etc.

No matter how you try to minimise these effects, some will always remain. Your capacitor in the question will have its own small internal resistance, and also the battery or power supply that you use to charge the capacitor will also have its own resistance. The wires that you use to connect the capacitor to the supply will in turn have their own resistance.

These are important effects to take into account when you try and ask what happens in an extreme case, such as in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, a capacitor is made of two plates separated by an isolator. Consequently, ideally there is an open circuit there.

If you connect the capacitor to a battery, as no current can flow, each plate would ideally inmediately acquire the same potential as the battery. You know that conductors ideally adquire the same potential all along them (in electrostatics).

However, as other answers say, there's always a resistive effect on wires and elements, and you will always have no instantanous load, but an exponential RC one.

Comment: *"ideally there is an open circuit there"* - that's not correct.  An ideal open circuit has zero capacitance (such that its impedance is infinite at all frequencies).

Comment: ? , in an ideal model of two wires ending in plates, when you connect a conductor to a fixed potential (battery), the whole conductor gets the same potential, so the same $\Delta V$ would appear on the plates.

Comment: An ideal capacitor is not an open-circuit; if it were, we would simply use open-circuits for capacitors.  It is true that the current through a capacitor is zero *if the voltage across is constant*, otherwise the current through is non-zero.  Moreover, your second paragraph is misleading; there *is* current when the battery is connected so it isn't correct to write "as no current can flow".

Comment: Of course, and this is what happens when it is directly connected to a battery: $V$ constant, no intensity. It actually is an open circuit in the limiting case of $R=0$, and that's the question, isn't it? Okay, there's an "infinite current" in an infinitely short time, so that charges rearrange to make the whole conductor be at the same potential. Both reasonings (electrostatics → same potential) and the limiting case of $e^{-t/RC}=0,\ if \  R\rightarrow 0$ drive to the same solution.

Comment: The point I have attempted to make is that the unqualified "capacitor is an open-circuit" is false.  It clearly isn't for time varying voltage across and so something like "a capacitor is like an open-circuit *at DC*" is more correct.  But this actually isn't a DC case since there is a time varying voltage across even in the ideal case.

Comment: Okay, now I understand. I just answered the case of a battery, because that what the question says, and I'm talking about the ideal case as I exlained in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Supposed, 
"I was looking for the fact when a capacitor is directly connected to battery without resistor what will happen?" 
means the theoretical case "... a capacitor not having the battery voltage (e.g. an unloaded one) is directly connected to a battery without impedance...", this case is the generalized case of 
[Capacitor discharging through no load?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/359877/capacitor-discharging-through-no-load/365417#365417),
where the battery has simply 0 voltage resulting in a short, since an ideal battery has no (inner) impedance.
In this case here we have the same contradiction at the exact time of switching/connecting, except that u2 is the battery voltage.
The  contradiction is again u1 <> u2. So the generalized equivalency is to define a number n1=n2 and at the same time n1<>n2.
This is why in reality these circuits can not exist.
It is a contradiction on the pure theoretical level. The statement in another answer
" In the context of ideal circuit theory, if an ideal constant voltage source with voltage ... across is, at time ...
, instantaneously connected to an ideal, uncharged capacitor, the voltage across the capacitor is a step
and so the current through is an impulse."
may be misleading, since a capacitor is also an ideal voltage supply in the exact time of connection. Or with an unloaded ideal capacitor, the ideal voltage source with zero impedance is connected to the unloaded ideal capacitor having also zero impedance resulting in a undefined contradiction, since it's an ideal shortcut (without any inductivities/resistors/capacitors involved) to an ideal voltage source. So v_s and v_c are not at all known, are not defined, can not be calculated in the very first moment of connection and it's more than doubtful that a step function can be calculated like stated in that answer. It's like connecting 2 ideal voltage sources with different voltages. So once again, there is no need ( if it's not even misleading) to argue with real circuits and it's unavoidable impedances, the circuit is already theoretically impossible resp. based on a contradiction. 
The last paragraph in the cited answer is again misleading: "So, to properly model this using ideal circuit elements, all of these 'parasitic' inductances and resistances must be added to the ideal circuit model to more accurately predict the physical charging current.", since "to more accurately predict the...current" should read "to avoid an unsolvable contradiction".