# Where does the energy go when I short a capacitor?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, capacitance

Please, help me find the mistake in this line of thought, or solve the inevitable question at the end.

- suppose there are two facing plates with different charge $Q_1$ and $Q_2$
- these two plates are the only thing in the universe
- because of the charge imbalance, there is electrical energy in the system
- now I connect the two plates with an ideal conductor of zero resistance
- the excess charge in one plate goes to the other plate, without dissipating heat
- at the end there is no more charge imbalance, no more electric energy in the system
- where did the energy go?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capacitor discharging through no load?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/359877/)

Comment: Firstly there will be dissipation. Otherwise the electrons would keep their kinetic energy. But either way where is the issue? Energy is conserved. Either in the form of heat or kinetic energy.

Comment: @FakeMob - thank you, i think it does not exactly answer my question. I was looking for an hint on the Radiation Resistance .. which I got in Dale's answer